# How to verify if object variable is set

Tags: php, oop

I have a `User` class which is created when a user logs in

```
$user = new User($userId);
```

Now to check if a user is logged in, I tried doing

```
if (isset($user)) {   // user is logged in

} else {   // user is not logged in

}
```

However, `isset()` doesn't appear to work for objects?  And I've also tried `is_object()`. Please advise! Hopefully there is a way to do this elegantly, perhaps

```
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {

}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`isset()` should work, object or not. You can also use

```
if ((isset($user)) and ($user instanceof User))
```

to check whether it is set *and* whether it is an object of the class `User`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that

```
new User($userid);
```

will *always* give you a `User` object, even though it's constructor, which probably looks up `$userid` in the database, may conclude that the object doesn't exist. You can throw an exception in the constructor for invalid `$userid`s and use a `try`/`catch` construct instead of your `isset()` test, or set a `User->valid` property in the constructor of users that do exist and check for that in your test.

See also this question for some more ideas: [PHP constructor to return a NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214724/php-constructor-to-return-a-null/2214769)

Answer (score 2):

If you edit your User class you can use $user->isLoggedIn()

```
class User {

private $logged_in = false;

...

public function login($uid) {
  ... login code
  $this->logged_in = true;
}

public function isLoggedIn() {
  return $this->logged_in;
}

...
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you have a user and want to check if he is logged in, it's a really bad idea to use `isset($user)` to determine if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

[isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) works with objects too. In fact it will work with anything as long as:

1. The variable has been declared in the current scope
2. The variable value is different than NULL

Comment: And how to check if the variable presented if the value is NULL?

Comment: @Intacto You mean $var === NULL?