# Can't get session component inside AppController constructor

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I need to get the roles of a user from the database.
I want to do it once and before everything. So I call a function from AppController constructor, which uses the session component. The function is given below

```
public function getRoles() {
    if ($this->Session->check('user_name')) {
        $username = $this->Session->read('user_name');
        $userdesc = $this->Session->read('user_desc');
        if ($userdesc === 'Student') {
            $this->roles['Student'] = true;
        } elseif ($userdesc === 'Faculty') {
            $this->roles['Teacher'] = true;

            $this->loadModel('UserRole');
            $userRolesList = $this->UserRole->getUserRolesList($username);

            $this->loadModel('Role');
            $rolesList = $this->Role->getRolesList();

            foreach($userRolesList as $userRole)
            {
                $this->roles[$rolesList[$userRole['UserRole']['role_id']]] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I load session component using an array. But I can't use `$this->Session`. If I load the component on the fly the function gives other errors. 
But if I call this function from beforeFilter() it creates no problem. Why I can't do it inside the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

you cant use $this inside constructor as $this is not instanciated yet.
explained here [PHP: using $this in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043538/php-using-this-in-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is just a wild guess but... I would not expect to have the AppController working if you override its constructor.
I am not sure why it does not work for you to have the function called in beforeFilter(), but if you insist I would try to do the following in your AppController:

```
__construct($request = null, $response = null) {
    parent::__contruct($request, $response);
    $this->Session = $this->Components->load('Session');
    getRoles();
    ....
}
```