# Stopping a class from being instanced if incorrect parameters

Tags: php, class

Is it possible to create a PHP class that would act like this:

```
class Foo
{
    function __construct($param)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($param))
        {
            // stop class
        }
    }
}

$a = new Foo(2);
$b = new Foo('test');

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

which will return

```
object(Foo)[1]
null
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP constructor to return a NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214724/php-constructor-to-return-a-null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I'm aware of to stop creating of a new object while not immediately terminating the script is to throw an exception:

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct($param) {
        if (!is_numeric($param)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Param is not numeric');
        }
    ...
}
```

Of course, you'd have to be sure and catch the exception in the calling code and handle the problem appropriately.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to throw an `\InvalidArgumentException` (from SPL).

Answer (score 2):

Create a `static create($param)` that returns a new instance or null if `$param` is invalid. You could also consider using Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to throw an exception and catch it from another function in the same scope as the variable declaration:

```
class Foo
{
    function __construct($param)
    {

        if( !is_numeric($param) )
            return true;
        else
            throw new Exception();

    }


}

function createFooObject($v){
    try{ $x = new Foo($v); return $x; }
    catch(Exception $e){
        unset($x);
    }
}

$a = createFooObject(2);
$b = createFooObject('test');



var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

Answer (score -3):

Just return `null` if the parameter is not numeric:

```
<?php

    class Foo{

       public function __construct($param = null){
          if( !is_numeric($param) ){
             return null;
          }
       }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score -3):

pretty much as you have it:

```
<?
public class newClass {

    public __CONSTRUCT($param = false){

        if(!is_numeric($param)){
            return false
        }

    }

}

$class = new newClass(1);
if($class){
    //success / is a number
}else{
    // fail, not a number, so remove the instance of the class
    unset($class);
}
?>
```

Setting `$param = false` inside the arguments for the constructor will tell the script to set it to false if there is no input

Comment: This is how I set up all my function and methods so I have control over every response. For me, default variables and methods all return true/false for processing to determine errors and what not.

Comment: So $class will be a boolean false rather than an instance of newClass if the constructor returns false. I wasn't aware of this. Where's it documented? It would be a useful link.